# .htaccess rewrite: subdomain as GET var and path as GET var

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Desired result:

```
http://example.com/                 -> index.php
http://www.example.com/             -> index.php
http://hello.example.com/           -> index.php?subdomain=hello
http://whatever.example.com/        -> index.php?subdomain=whatever
http://example.com/world            -> index.php?path=world
http://example.com/world/test       -> index.php?path=world/test
http://hello.example.com/world/test -> index.php?subdomain=hello&path=world/test
```

With the .htaccess I have right now, I can achieve one or the other re-mapping, but not both at the same time.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1

# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

I'm having a hard time combining the two...any pointers, please?

**EDIT**
The unwanted behavior I'm experiencing now is that if I have a subdomain and a path after .com/, only the subdomain will be passed through, ie:

```
http://hello.example.com/world-> index.php?subdomain=hello
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582265/mod-rewrite-setting-subdomain-and-directory-to-get-variable

Comment: maybe it's better if you combine VirtualHosts for handling subdomains, and .htaccess for handling url rewrite. Two years after, how do you solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the first rule to add the `subdomain` parameter, without changing the URI, then use the 2nd rule to route the URI to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1

# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The second rule *needs* to have the `QSA` flag, otherwise the first rule's query string gets lost.

Comment: Ah, 'query string append', interesting!  Very informative, thanks.

Comment: Hi Jon Lin how to rewrite like                   http://admin.example.com/  -> http://example.com/admin/

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to work for the OP's last example (http://hello.example.com/world/test). It will repeat the second segment (/test) twice in the 'path=' var as '/world/test/test'.

Comment: The first rule will create an infinite loop since htaccess restarts after every rule and the subdomain it is finding in the condition still exists. For it to work propperly you would need to add a condition to test if the rule has already put the subdomain  in the query string. EXAMPLE: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)path=?(.*)$

Comment: The first rule doesn't have a L flag, the 2nd rule gets applied and ends the loop