# Mod_Rewrite setting subdomain and directory to GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I programmed a website that I want to be multilingual, the separate languages should be accessable via subdomain, for example en.example.com, de.example.com and so on.

Furthermore I already have a rewrite to set a "directory" as GET variable, that changes example.com/name to example.com/index.php?page=name.

No matter what I tried I find no possibilities to properly combine the two codes I need to use with these respective problems. Each in it's own works, I only need a method to combine both, so that en.example.com/name will be rewritten to example.com/index.php?page=name&lang=en

What I use for directories to GET variables

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\w*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

What I found for subdomains to GET variables

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?lang=%1 [L]
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks for the hint, however as I haven't used that flag before and examples only suggest it when using URLs like example.com/name/?lang=en I can't seem to find a way to correctly insert it. Do you maybe have an example on how that should look like with my above mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to combine your 2 rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! worked around it with the $_SERVER array, but this is nice to know for future reference :D