# Use subdomain to make get parameter for php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I found couple of same questions but their answers not working for me. They dont make folders acceptable. Here is my question:

I want to translate:

```
test.localhost/folder/&anothervar=1
```

to

```
localhost/folder/index.php?subdomain=test&anothervar=1
```

I will use it on some domain too I'm developing the site right now so I need to figure out how to make this work before another parts.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303858/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-as-get-var-and-path-as-get-var

Comment: @Ali no, I want to make it work on localhost I already tested everything on that post too

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go into your `.htaccess` file to solve this.

Once there, enter the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/?test=%1 [R=301,L]
```

This will essentially convert `subdomain.domain.com` into `domain.com/?test=subdomain`

You can take it from there and add additional parameters.

For other subdomain related stuff, check [this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/apache-mod_rewrite-and-examples) out.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have already tested it, not working on "http://test.localhost/folder/index.php&anotherVal=123ü" + not sending extra get values

Answer (score 0):

To translate

- test.localhost/folder/&anothervar=1

to

- localhost/folder/index.php?subdomain=test&anothervar=1

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)if host value is =="test.example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.([^.]+) [NC]
#2)And the uri is =="folder/&anychar"
#Redirect the request to "http://%1/folder/index.php?test=sub&anychar
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/&(.+)$ /$1/index.php?test=%1&$2 [B,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, only problem is website isnt test.example.com it should be test.localhost/folder/

Comment: The rule matches any dyanamic subdomains and uris.

Comment: Are you testing this on a home server?

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing on localhost (I need for localhost for now, I'm developing the website right now)

Comment: There's no .com so rule fails.

Comment: @SarpAykent try the updated rule, ive remove tld from the pattern

Comment: Oh I get the problem, htaccess redirects the url. I dont want that I want to make virutal subdomains that points same site I dont want to translate the url (I just wanna translate it for php)

Comment: @SarpAykent Remove the **R=301** flag and use an absolute target path instead of the full url, if you want to internally redirect the request. Try the edited version.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but I started using vhost I'm using like www.example.com right now can you update one more time please ?

Comment: I'm using 'subdomain.example.com' right now can you please edit it like that  (without folder)

Comment: I have tested this one of yours not working.
```
RewriteEngine on

#1)if host value is =="test.example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.([^.]+)\.com [NC]
#2)And the uri is =="folder/&anychar"
#Redirect the request to "http://example.com/index.php?test=sub&anychar
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/&(.+)$ http://%2.com/index.php?test=%1&$2 [B,L]```

Comment: one more problem is, I found the some rules that makes the trick but problem is it still behave's like subdomain what i mean is php dont use same session on all subdomains It starts new session for each