# how to redirect to a folder in public_html in Centos Apache Server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I want to redirect to a folder based to the requested uri [sub-domain].

Let suppose I Have public_html as my root folder, in which I have some projects,
Now I want to create something that allows me to point to the project folder based on the requested URL.

Like in Public_HTMl i have:

**public_html**

```
    project1

    project2

    project3

    project4
```

Now if my subdomain is **project1.example.com**,

then my root should be **project1** folder, if the URL is project1 then my root will be **project2**.

How do I do this? I think **virtual hosts** can help me but how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you create an example based on my situation ? like i have three folder in root , and three subdomains, how to handle them

Answer (score 1):

I would add an "catch all vhost" for all subdomains and main domain, and handle all requests via `htaccess`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303858/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-as-get-var-and-path-as-get-var) is an good example of how to catch the subdomain and use it for internal redirections.

Comment: Can you please create me an example for the same?? i did not understand it